# iPhone: how to send images and files using xmpp framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xmppframework

I am able to do one to one chat using xmppframework but now i want to send images and file into chat.

I am trying using turn socket but not able to get the functionality as this always says "Turn connect failed !"

Please help me to get rid this problem and able to send the images and file.

Thanks,

Comment: I know this may not be applicable to you, but have you considered uploading the image/file to your server and then sending back a link to the sender for him to send to the receiver. You can delete the file/image once the receiver's client has deleted the file

Comment: Thanks AKV. I will check it out but this is not the solution as open fire gives the functionality of sending images and file.

Comment: I just reread your question and it seems like you're doing this on iOS, I would highly recommend you don't directly send files directly over XMPP on iOS. Due to the way iOS apps are used, the connection can get severed at any time if the client puts the app into background or the phone auto-locks.

Comment: @user2090431 Hi,have you solved the file share over XMPP? Me too stuck with same issue.Can you please help me?